# What is the difference between loadingIndicatorSource and defaultSource props in react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, ecmascript-6

The defination for **[loadingIndicatorSource](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#loadingindicatorsource)** and **[defaultSource](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#defaultsource)** properties are almost same for both.

Please, can anyone tell what is the difference between **[loadingIndicatorSource](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#loadingindicatorsource)** and **[defaultSource](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#defaultsource)** props in react-native?

Answer (score 7):

Well as you said they are really similar but personally i would use

**defaultSource** for a placeholder image (A static image to display while loading the image source.)

while

**loadingIndicatorSource** you can use it to display a spinner while waiting the image is loaded

Not such an useful answer but hope it will help!
Bye!

Comment: Maybe be helpful => https://stackoverflow.com/a/62510268/11302100

Answer (score 0):

On react native: "0.64.2", defaultSource and loadingIndicatorSource are not working.