# How to specify the more than one uri for the image in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, ecmascript-6

This [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#source) says that:

> This prop can also contain **several remote URLs**, specified together with their **width** and **height** and potentially with **scale/other URI arguments**.

Can anyone tell how to specify more than one URI's for image component in react-native? There is no such example for this definition. And also how to pass the height and width arguments along with the URI as this [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#source) states.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the answer in the `react-native` source code, specifically `/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image` and the files `ImageSourcePropType` and `ImageProps`.

According to `ImageSourcePropType`, when passing a URI object, it should be in this shape (meaning it can have any of the defined properties as long as the type matches what is expected):

```
const ImageURISourcePropType = PropTypes.shape({
  uri: PropTypes.string,
  bundle: PropTypes.string,
  method: PropTypes.string,
  headers: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string),
  body: PropTypes.string,
  cache: PropTypes.oneOf([
    'default',
    'reload',
    'force-cache',
    'only-if-cached',
  ]),
  width: PropTypes.number,
  height: PropTypes.number,
  scale: PropTypes.number,
});
```

And according to `ImageProps`,  `source` permits an object of shape `ImageSourcePropType`, an array of those objects, or a number (for local assets, the statement `require('imgs/image1.png')` returns a number identifying that asset). Here is the code:

```
const ImageSourcePropType = PropTypes.oneOfType([
  ImageURISourcePropType,
  // Opaque type returned by require('./image.jpg')
  PropTypes.number,
  // Multiple sources
  PropTypes.arrayOf(ImageURISourcePropType),
]);
```

So the `source` prop will accept a single object that matches `ImageURISourcePropType` or an array of objects that match.

So to pass multiple remote images and specify the widths it would be something like

```
<Image
  source={[
    {
      uri: 'https://image.location.com',
      width: 500,
      height: 500
    },
    {
      uri: 'https://image2.location.com',
      width: 600,
      height: 600
    },
    {
      uri: 'https://image3.location.com',
      width: 700,
      height: 700
    },
  ]}
/>
```

Comment: Can you please answer this question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013841/what-is-the-difference-between-loadingindicatorsource-and-defaultsource-props-in

Comment: I'm not sure, they seem indentical. I would prefer `defaultSource`, as it seems like `loadingIndicatorSource` is meant to refer more to a local gif that would be used as a loading animation whereas `defaultSource` is more like a fallback image

Comment: Both **defaultSource** and **loadingIndicatorSource** properties take value same as **source** property i-e **require()** or **{}**?